# How does domain works in openerp as well as xml?

Tags: odoo

I am working on domain and I'm not getting how it works exactly , below I have given my code pls tell me how could I use it and how it fits into my code.

```
class test_cl(osv.osv):

    _name = 'test.cl'
    _columns ={
            'name':fields.char('Name',size=20),
            'age':fields.integer('Age',size=10),
            'gender':fields.selection([('m','M'),('f','F')],'gender'),
            'tel_no':fields.char('Telephone',size=100,),
            'emailid':fields.char('Email id',size=20),
            'website':fields.char('Web address',size=20),
            'company':fields.char(
                    'Company name',
                    size=100,
                    domain=[('choice','=',YES)],
                    change_default=True,
                    ),
            'desg':fields.char('Designation',size=100),
            'wght':fields.float('Weight'),
            'choice':fields.selection(
                    [('yes','YES'),('no','NO')],
                    'Working',
                    required=True,
                    ),
            }

    _defaults = {
            'age':30,
            }
test_cl()
```

Answer (score 2):

Domain restricts your record to display. It is a condition for your records. For example.

```
_columns = {
    'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner', domain=[('name', '=', 'greywind')])
}
```

So when you click on the `partner_id` field on the web client. it will run a search method &  execute a query like

```
select id from res_partner where name='greywind';
```

and you can see only partner with name *greywind*.

Domains are tuples, the structure is `(field, operator, value)`.
Field is the data in the database, Operator is the comparison, `=` equal, `!=` not equal, `>` greater than, `<` less than, etc. Value is the data you want to compare with the field, it can be another database field, a constant or a calculated value.

Answer (score -1):

Domains limits possible choices for many2one, many2many and one2many fields to use only objects that satisfies . For example in stock.production.lot

```
'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', required=True, domain=[('type', '<>', 'service')]),
```

allows to use only products that are not service. In your code there is no fields related to other objects so there is no application for domains.

Comment: Domains can be used to restrict records by regular fields as well as `many` fields.